# Get Users Comment Karma Broken Down by Subreddit?

Tags: reddit, praw

I'm sure this is simple but I'm at a loss; How do I get a user's comment karma broken down by subreddit? I can get the link Karma as demonstrated on the praw tutorial and I can retrieve comments but I can't seem to figure out where I can get the comment votes from?  My ultimate goal is to create a composite score of link + comments karma for users a subreddit. Any hints or explanations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own questions.  It's just a matter of editing the sample code from the PRAW documentation to get_comments() rather than get_submitted().